# Two animations on same element not working

Tags: css, css-animations

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfZ5k/show/) **|** [**Source**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfZ5k/)

At `#lt`, I used two animations,

```
animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
```

But it doesn't work, even the first animation doesn't show work.

But if I remove the second one, the first starts working

---

**CSS**

```
#lt {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(4);
    animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
    animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes fadeInStamp {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    30% { opacity: 1; }
    60% { transform: scale(.7); }
    80% { transform: scale(1.3); }
    100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1); }
}

@keyframes leftArrowBounce {
    0% {  }
    50% { transform: translateX(-10px); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="lt">&lt;</div>
```

Comment: use two div give one animation to each div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`animation` is like any other CSS, if you specify a new value for the property then it will (depending on specificity) override the old one. So when you include your `leftArrowBounce` animation, the `fadeInStamp` animation is being ignored.
In this case, you're not seeing anything happen because your element has an `opacity` of `0`, but the `leftArrowBounce` animation is occuring as you can see by setting `opacity: 1;`:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfZ5k/1/

The size (i.e. `scale`) is also changing here because your `leftArrowBounce` is overwriting the `transform` property, and hence `scale` gets reset as part of the `leftArrowBounce` animation.

To include multiple animations, you can just comma-seperate them:

```
animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both,
           leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
```

**HOWEVER**, it seems that this is currently buggy when used in conjunction with a delay value. Certainly for Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=178413

**ALSO**, the fact that you're changing `transform` in both animations, and have both of them with an `animation-fill-mode` set to `both` causes issues. It works in Firefox, Opera and IE using:

```
animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 0s 1 normal forwards,
           leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal forwards;
```

Along with setting the first frame of `leftArrowBounce` explicitly:

```
@keyframes leftArrowBounce {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    50% { transform: translateX(-10px); }
    100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/yfZ5k/6/  (again, doesn't currently work in chrome)

Comment: Hey thanks for the great info, its always helpful to know about the bugs. I finally decided to club the two animations together in 1 long and complex animation, a lot of math but now it works great on every browser.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap one animation element with other

```
 <div id="wrap-lt">
   <div id="lt">
       &lt;
   </div>
 </div>
```

then add animation to each element

```
#wrap-lt {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font: normal 15em/300px sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(4);
    -moz-transform: scale(4);
    -ms-transform: scale(4);
    -o-transform: scale(4);
    transform: scale(4);
    -webkit-animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
    -moz-animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
    -ms-animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
    -o-animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
    animation: fadeInStamp .5s linear 1 normal both;
}
#wrap-lt #lt{
    -webkit-animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
       -moz-animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
        -ms-animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
         -o-animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
            animation: leftArrowBounce .5s linear 1.5s 1 normal both;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vineethkrishnan007/82GxW/)